# How do I pass parameters to Play Store if app is uninstalled with the new intent scheme on Chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, deep-linking

I'm deeplinking in Chrome with the following URL:

`intent:///dispatch/US?utm_campaign=US_MB#Intent;scheme=my_app;package=com.my_app;end`

I'd like to pass this "utm_campaign" parameter and value to the Play Store if "my_app" is uninstalled on the current device.  Is there a way to do this within this intent scheme?

Documentation and previous questions/answers were inconclusive for this specific circumstance.  Please let me know if you have any follow up q's.